# How to set autolayout constraint for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode8.2

I want to set the view on iPhone(portrait) and iPad(landscape) such that:
1. on iPhone view must take full width of screen (In portrait). Please check following screen shot.

[image]

2. on iPad the same view must be of size 500px width (in landscape)

[image]

How should I do it in one view only?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve this using 'Vary for Traits' option, please check following image :

[image]

Using this option I am able to set the constraints specific to iPhone or iPad.